# Is it okay to look for good posts to upvote after downvoting a post

Tags: discussion, questions

Sometimes after I downvote a bad post I'll feel bad. Maybe I shouldn't, but that's not what this is about. Is it okay to look through their other posts for good ones to upvote? As long as I'm only upvoting legitimately good posts that stand up on their own of course.

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: No, votes are not personal, and votes are not cast on people. Vote on content alone.

Comment: and what do you do if, in your research for an upvote worthy post, you find absolute trash. You **don't** downvote it, cause your imaginary "karma" isn't balanced?

Comment: @user4642212 maybe they aren't supposed to be, but people certainly take them take them personally

Comment: Yes, and they should stop. You should not contribute to this misunderstanding, and it should not inform your behavior.

Comment: I've noticed I got a lot of downvotes and I was wondering how I could improve my question. Is it because it is opinion based? Should I have found the answer somewhere else? Not complaining, just want to improve

Comment: Votes on meta are often meant as agreement or disagreement. So lots of people just don't agree with it :)

Comment: @Scratte Ah! That makes more sense. Thanks

Comment: I strongly disagree with the premise here, but I do appreciate the fact that you've *asked* whether this is the right thing, rather than just going and doing it. I also want others to see this Q&A. That's why I've upvoted it. But, generally, questions with objectionable premises receive lots of downvotes on Meta, and @Scratte is entirely correct.

Comment: Unbalanced curation is already bad enough.  Some users have more than 5 times as many upvotes as downvotes.  Such poor curation should be discouraged.

Comment: Just imagine what type of content would get posted if users *received* reputation when they got downvotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The general rule is that we are not allowed to target any user with our votes. **Votes should be on *content*, not on *users*.** Do not go to the user's profile page to look for stuff to vote on, whether up or down.

If you do happen to come across posts that you feel deserve your votes, then vote. Do not pay attention who was the author. If it so happens that multiple of these posts are from the same user, then do not feel bad.

**You should never feel bad about your votes.** Votes are there for us to rate content. We do not rate users. We do not use votes to punish or reward users.<sup>*</sup> Voting is your obligation to the community to let other readers know of good quality helpful content and separate it from the low-quality or harmful suggestions.

<sub><sup>*</sup> When a user gets an upvote, the system rewards them with 10 reputation points, and when they get a downvote, the system punishes them with -2 reputation points. The distinction is when you are abusing the system to punish/reward a user versus normal behaviour. If the system or moderators notice that you are abusing your votes, then such votes will be undone and you might get suspended.</sub>